# GET and POST request to same route

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am to perform a GET request upon loading a page, and then when the user submits a form, I want to perform a POST request on that same route.

Would this code be correct?

frontend

```
await fetch("http://localhost:3000/foo", {
            method: 'GET',
        })

await fetch("http://localhost:3000/foo", {
            method: 'POST',
        })
```

backend

```
app.post('/foo', (req, res) => {
  //do something 1
})

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  //do something 2
})
```

Or would I do something like

```
app.route('/foo')
  .get(getHandler)
  .post(postHandler)

function getHandler(req, res) {
  // do something 1
}
function postHandler(req, res) {
  // do something 2
}
```

Comment: Yes... that's all correct. Did it not work when you tried?

Comment: I just wanted to double check to make sure my thinking was correct.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your first code is correct, but I don't think the second one works. I recommend you use the following syntax because it's the most widely used (I don't know of any other method) :

```js
app.post('/foo', (req, res) => { 
   //do something 1 
})

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => { 
   //do something 2 
})
```

Comment: Hi, while your answer may be correct, it's better to explain why you recommend this solution. Please read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer),Thank you!